# Reconstruction of 3D model using three 2D images (looking at the same object in 3 different views)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I came across a requirement to reconstruct 3 dimensional image of an object using three cameras placed around it such that it (each camera's field of view together) covers the entire object under view.

- I have already worked a little on stereo vision (using two cameras). In this, we obtain a 3D point cloud. I don't think this will be necessary in my case since I need not calculate the exact x, y and z distances. I only have to get a 3D model. Is my approach right? I have read about Stereo Vision using multiple cameras. Should I use this?
- I came across [this comment by Image Analyst](http://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/154714-how-can-i-convert-2d-images-to-a-3d-image): "*images must actually undergo a filtered back projection reconstruction process to build the 3D image from the images taken at different angles.*" I did not understand this clearly. I do not have a stack of images, I have only 3 images of the same object but with different views. How should I proceed with this? What are the terms which are used in my case? Is it called 3D Reconstruction?
- I also saw about SfM (Structure from Motion). My object / scene is not in motion.
- I saw [this code](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/PROJECTS/Reconstruction/index.html) available. This too takes different slices of a brain and converts them into a 3D image. Is there anyway I can alter this code to suit my need or is it a completely different application?

As far as I have understood, with the three images (of different views of same object) I have to first match features (say SIFT) and then get the disparity (?). Or should I use Image stitching and deal with the stitched image (maybe create a 3D point cloud with this)?

Please tell me how to go about this application. What are the necessary topics I should read about?

My application is to only capture the object in 3D (using 3 cameras) and save this 3D image.

Regards,

Meghana.

Edit:

- I have also come across Three-View Geometry (PART III of "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision by Hartley and Zisserman"). I don't think this is the same as what I want. In my case the scenes wouldn't overlap to a large extent. The field of view of each camera would overlap only a little (the cube's edges, as shown below), it won't be the same as in a stereo pair of cameras looking at a common scene. So stereo matching won't be feasible. Is my understanding correct? How should I deal with it?

[image]

Comment: Structure from Motion does not mean that your object or scene is moving, but rather that your *camera* is. Having three images of the same object from different views is equivalent to a moving camera. Thus researching SfM should be your next step.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other concepts apart from SfM?  I had read [this article](http://openmvg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/software/SfM/SfM/). Should I use openMVG? I have never used it earlier.

Comment: I have never used OpenMVG, so I can't say.

Comment: This paper gives a good overview of 3D reconstruction using stereo, and migh be of some help: [link] (http://www.micsymposium.org/mics2014/ProceedingsMICS_2014/mics2014_submission_7.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! I wants to know more about the implementation. Are you aware of any documents?

Comment: I need to stack multi 2d Images to 3d.

Comment: The problem as described is still underspecified.  What sort of 3D model do you want to recover?  You're probably not going to get a polygonal surface unless you make a lot of strong assumptions about the shape that is being reconstructed.  (For example, if you know it is a sphere you can probably recover its radius and location.)  You might be able to create a point cloud, although usually SfM uses many more than three images.  In short, this problem may be harder than you realize.  If there are any factors that could make it simpler, you should share them.

Comment: @nhowe thank you for your reply. I have 3 images that are 2d. I need to stack these images to be 3d.